# How to write iOS framework for React Native components

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-frameworks

I have few components written in Objective-C and Swift.
When I want to use it in any react native project, i will manually copy those native components and creating a bridge.

Now i want to use the same components in multiple projects, so i'm thinking of putting all those native components along with bridging part into one framework.

To start with i developed a simple framework with a simple native view..as below

[image]

When i try to run ComponentTest project, frameworks fails to build with error saying RCTViewManager.h is not found. I'm sure this dependency will be available in all projects which uses my framework.

> ComponentTest/node_modules/tmobcomponents/ios/TMobileNativeComponents/TMobileNativeComponents/components/SimpleView/SimpleViewManager.h:12:9: Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'TMobileNativeComponents.SimpleViewManager': '/Users/someone/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ComponentTest-auqzutioszphtnhfizcfhndibnnl/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/React/RCTViewManager.h'

Is it possible to build a framework without adding ReactNative dependency in framework, because React native dependency(RCTViewManager) will be available in the project which uses my framework.

How to accomplish this (Native views and also bridging part(native) ) should be in framework

Comment: I’m interested in doing this too.

Comment: any update or article about this?